A persistent hash of a Python function code for caching
I am running data processing jobs that are
- Inputs (Pandas Series)
- Python function
I'd like to make this so that if inputs (function arguments) and the function itself (function body and code) are the same, I do not run the calculation, but just cache the results on the disk.
While function results are easy to cache in-process memory, in my case there might be multiple runs over multiple months. Also the underlying Python source code may change, with the change of underlying Python code.
I'd need to detect when the function code has changed and have a unique hash for each function by its code. If the function body changes I need to rerun the calculation and write the new cached result to the disk.
E.g. detect and hash the difference between
def my_task(a: pd.Series, b: pd.Series):
     return a+b

And:
def my_task(a: pd.Series, b: pd.Series):
     return a + b - 2

How can I calculate a hash for a Python function code? Or anything that is close enough to this?
Furthermore, these Python functions can reside within Jupyter Notebooks, not just in Python modules.

You could just hash the text, but then it would also detect a "difference" between return a+b and return a + b.

Good idea. How can I access the text (of a function)?

@MikkoOhtamaa try this

@jonrsharpe: To avoid issues like a simple PEP8 spacing change foiling this, you'd probably want to involve the ast module to get the actual syntax tree associated with the function.

Determining if two functions are identical is generally undecidable.

Thank you @chepner - I am aware of this, so a close approximation is enough and the worst that can happen is that the cache needs to be manually purged.

Closing my own question as duplicate, as I found an existing implementation on SO.

Are you familiar with joblib.Memory?  I think it already does exactly what you want. And if not, you could check its source code to see how it calculates the necessary hashes.

Thahnk you Kale. This looks really promising.

It does not fit for the purpose as it says Across sessions, function cache is identified by the function’s name

The cache is regenerated if the function's code changes.  The quote you gave is just saying that if you assign two different functions the same name, you'll have to re-evaluate the function more often than if you'd given them different names.  Try it; you'll see that editing the function's code will cause the function to be re-run.
